# A word for attempting to induce/force nostalgia

Tags: single-word-requests

For instance, at Christmas time people often attempt to induce a state of nostalgia. Listening to old music, telling old stories, baking certain foods, ect.

I believe I've heard a term for this but I just can't find it via google search.

Comment: Could "sentimentalism" be the word?

Comment: 'harking back to the good old days' - i appreciate this isn't a single word, but if you mumble it out is sounds like one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentimental:

> Having, showing, or caused by strong or extravagant tenderness or sadness, often in an idealized way: *"He had no sentimental illusions about poverty's virtues*" (Sherill Tippins).

[American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sentimental)

It is the 'inducing or forcing nostalgia' that makes being sentimental into something syrupy, a negative.

Comment: @Gustavson - Yes, when I saw the similarity, I already upvoted you at that time. We must have been typing at the same time.